# looking for example on how to setup and run Splunk on Windows

Tags: logging, splunk

Im looking for an example of how to setup splunk on windows. setup data inputs from different source ie a file, a local database, and a remote database or file using a fowarder. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

splunk documentation is pretty clear with a video for the same task.

If you are looking for a log file to upload and practice , I would recommend "exploring splunk " book, it has url to get sample data.
If you want to use live log file, I would suggest to install a web server (Apache)or application server like Weblogic , deploy an application into it, use the log folder as input for splunk.